# How to find difference between two dates

Tags: php

```
$start = "2015-01-01 10:00:00";

$end = "2015-05-05 12:06:06";


$x = strtotime($start);

$y = strtotime($end);

$z = abs($y - $x);

$days = floor($z / (60 * 60 * 24));
$years = floor($z / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));

$months = floor(($z - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));

$days = floor(($z - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60 * 24));

$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $days * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60));

$minuts = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $days * 60 * 60 * 24 - $hours * 60 * 60) / 60);

$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $days * 60 * 60 * 24 - $hours * 60 * 60 - $minuts * 60));
```

Output is:

```
4 month 4 days 1 hour 6 minute 6 seconds
```

Expected output is :

```
4 month 4 days 2 hour 6 minute 6 seconds
```

Comment: Take a look at Datetime-objects and the (Datetime->diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function.. Btw, the hour diff is correct... If you take summer / winter time into considderation...

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is a good way to work with dates in PHP:

```
$start = "2015-01-01 10:00:00";
$end = "2015-05-05 12:06:06";

$d1 = new DateTime($start);
$d2 = new DateTime($end);

$iv = $d2->diff($d1);

echo $iv->format('%m month, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

Comment: To Op, this is the most straight forward, but @pavlovich might want to edit the answer to the expected output of the OP. 4 month 4 days 2 hour 6 minute 6 seconds

Comment: Just wondering but doesn't %m for months and %m for minutes output the same? ;)

Comment: @Naruto %i will display minutes :p

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong on your code, you probably need to include your default timezone, like for me Im in Africa, so i always use the below line to set up my timezone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Harare');
```

you just need to fine out what is your region and then assign it to the method `date_default_timezone_set();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = new DateTime('2007-09-01 04:10:58');
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('2012-09-11 10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->days.' days total<br>';
echo $since_start->y.' years<br>';
echo $since_start->m.' months<br>';
echo $since_start->d.' days<br>';
echo $since_start->h.' hours<br>';
echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s.' seconds<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
$start = date_create('2015-01-01 10:00:00');
$end = date_create('2015-05-05 12:06:06');
$diffObj = date_diff($start, $end);
//accesing days
$days = $diffObj->d;
//accesing months
$months = $diffObj->m;
//accesing years
$years = $diffObj->y;
//accesing hours
$hours=$diffObj->h;
//accesing minutes
$minutes=$diffObj->i;
//accesing seconds
$seconds=$diffObj->s;
echo '<center>';
echo '' . $days . ' day(s), ' . $months . ' month(s), ' . $years . 'year(s), '.$hours.' hour(s),'.$minutes.' minute(s), '.$seconds.' second(s) </b>';
echo '</center>';
```